# Replace JSON content in a .txt file with just a String (WSO2 Integrator)

Tags: json, xml, wso2, transformation, wso2-esb

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

> {
>         "name":"John"    }

I need to replace the JSON with just the "John" part so the .txt file contains nothing but

**John**

inside it (*just a regular text, no quotes around it*). 
I am using the WSO2 Integrator. I have looked into the PayloadFactory and the Smooks mediators but they only give back either JSON or xml. I am also looking at the Enrich mediator but no matter how I twist it, it doesnt affect the text file at all.

Comment: If you know that the input is `{"name":"John"}` then you don't need to do any processing, just output "John". The reason you need a program is presumably that the input might be something different, like `{"name":"Jane"}`. But then the question becomes, what is the possible range of inputs that the program might encounter? And what is the program required to do if the input is outside this range?

Comment: Once you read the file try using the expression json-eval($.name).

Comment: @amg_amit I did try with json-eval($.name) and it does replace the content of the file with "John"... the problem is - I don't need the quotes around the name.

Comment: If you do not require the quote then after you fetch the data using the expression try using the substring before and after "" to remove the quotes, if this is not feasible then try using payload mediator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
     <property name="name" expression="json-eval($.name)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <ms11:text xmlns:ms11="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ms11:text>
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:name"/>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
     <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, Erandika! This did the job